# SPA: Client Side Session Handling in Combination with OAuth Authorization Code Flow with PKCE

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, owasp

We have a Single Page Application (SPA) and OAuth authentication.

We will use the [Authorization Code Flow with PKCE](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce), because it's considered as the safest method for client side authentication.
But OAuth is only about authentication.

**Considerations**

- What about a safe session management? How do I take care, that the OAuth token could not be stolen?
- In classical web applications we used cookies with secure, http-only and same-site-policy flags.
- One pattern could be the [Backend for Frontend Pattern](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/). But we would like to have a pure frontend application.
- CSPs might help. But if not configured 100% there will be still loop holes. Also we have some (trusted) thirdparty code to include which would lead to a complex CSP configuration.
- Of course we care about XSS. But also we think, that we never can guarantee, that the application is 100% XSS safe.

**Solution?**

There are a lot of best practises about OAuth itself, but even the [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html) does not give a precise advice of how to store tokens in a SPA.

Our solution might be to store the token in a browser session storage. This should be safe against CSS attacks (we have no user generated content, therefore there should be no stored XSS).

**Final questions**

- Is the browser session storage safe for storing tokens?
- What attacks might be possible?
- What countermeasures must be taken?

Comment: Have a look at [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096336/why-is-bff-pattern-deemed-safer-for-spas) from a work colleague of mine, which I think provided some good answers on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Backend for Frontend Pattern**

If there are few external APIs, the [Backend for Frontend Pattern](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/) might be a good choice. The downside is that you have to proxy each external API. This brings extra effort and inflexibility, if you are using many external APIs.

**Content Security Policies**

The best way to secure the token in the browsers is using [CSPs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). Of course you need to take care, that the CSPs don't have any loopholes. You should validate the CSPs by a CSP validator.

**Session Storage**

Session storage is only a weak countermeasure:

- An attacker might manipulate the authentication process via a XSS vulnerability and could also obtain the tokens.
- Manipulating the authentication process only needs more sophisticated knowledge, than just taking an existing token from localStorage.